# Why is JS not working & App Scripts won't run doGet() with either e or event?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Last night I started following a Basic Web App video. I followed it to the letter & it was working perfectly until I the last bit where I change things. Today I decided to started from nothing & recreated it. After weeks of learning how to code, nothing I've can explain why the very simple thing won't work on app scripts. I've all day, spent hours, use different emails, & nothing works. I can't get the JS to work. I've gave permissions a & I've copied letter by letter from basic web app youtube video. None of is working & I don't understand why. I'm frustrated. I can recreated everything else but the very start of the code is not working.

Also, when I use doGet(e) or doGet(event) variations, the code stopped working but it only worked as doGet(). Why? Sorry, I'm frustrated. I've spent all day trying to figure why this dam thing won't work.

Here's the basic code:
Under the code tab, I've use

```js
function userClicked(name) {
  var url = "This the url of the sheet. I've remove it to post my question.com";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  ws.appendRow([name]);
}
```

Under the page tag, I entered the following script. It's only 1 script.

```js
<script>
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
  function doStuff(){
    var name = document.getElementById(sname).value;
    google.script.run.userClicked(name);
    document.getElementById("sname").value = "";
  }
</script>
```

I can get to load the page but it won't run the js or send data to the spreadsheet url. It worked last night perfectly. I've gave permission to run the code.

Also, I've use function doGet() with different versions. One without doGet(event),doGet(e), & doGet(). Only the doGet() works.

Comment: Any errors in View >executions?

Comment: You don't need the parameter to the function named `e` or `event` unless something is being passed to the `doGet()` function.  The letter "e" is used because it's the first letter in the word "event"  Most of the time, there is no event object being passed to the `doGet()` function.  Hit the f12 key to open up the web developer tools window.  There is a tab for "Console"  Look for errors in the console.  Many of the errors you'll see have nothing to do with your app.  For your server side code in the gs file, you can use `Logger.log(name)` to see what your code is doing.

Comment: Could you share a sanitized copy of the project you are working on (remove sensitive information)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
var name = document.getElementById(sname).value;
```

to

```
var name = document.getElementById("sname").value;
```